# Node.js javascript - call function from external script server-side

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like my Node.JS website to send an email every time a form is submitted on the contact-us page.

HTML page

```
<form class="contact_us_form" method="post">
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Public.js

```
router.post('/contact_us', function(req, res, next)
{
   console.log('FORM SUBMITTED FROM CONTACT_US PAGE');
   sendMail();
});
```

utils.js

```
function sendMail() 
{
     //function body
}
```

When I press the submit button on the html then sendMail is being called but it cannot be found, so the html page and the public.js files are linked properly, but public.js and utils.js are not.

How would I go about linking the function "sendMail" to Public.js? This function is meant to run on the server, **NOT** on the client.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeJS uses the concept of [*modules*](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html). You'd export `sendMail` from `utils.js`:

```
exports.sendMail = sendMail;
```

...and import it in `public.js`:

```
var sendMail = require("./utils.js").sendMail;

// ...

sendMail(/*...*/);
```

or:

```
var utils = require("./utils.js");

// ...

utils.sendMail(/*...*/);
```

---

Here's a complete example:

`utils.js`:

```
function sendMail() {
    console.log("I'm sending mail now...");
}

exports.sendMail = sendMail;
```

`public.js`:

```
var utils = require("./utils.js");
utils.sendMail();
```

Running it:

```
$ node public.js
I'm sending mail now...
```

Comment: It still doesn't recognize  `sendMail` as a function for some odd reason. Do I need to place the line `exports.sendMail = sendMail;` before or after the function declartion inside `utils.js`?

Comment: @Omrii: If it's a function *declaration*, it doesn't matter. But at the end is usually best. I've added a complete example you can run (it's not really much longer than the earlier code blocks :-) ).

Comment: The example you've written up in public.js worked great but the solution for utils.js was different. The fix was the following: `module.exports = { sendMail : function () { /* func body */ } } `

Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Omrii: You're allowed to either replace `exports` (as you've done) or just add to it (as in the above), both work.